# react-router Route component constructor is not called when props are updated in BrowserRouter component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor, react-router, react-props

I have a React app. I'm using `react` and `react-router`. [Here's the sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/00zomy7xj0).

I have an `App.js` file like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Items from './Items';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ items: ['a', 'b', 'c'] });
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;

    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Items {...props} items={items} />} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

In this file, in the `componentDidMount`, I'm getting data from an API, then passing it to the `Items` component. On the initial page load, of course `items` will be an empty array, and then it will eventually have content.

In my `Items.js` file, I have:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Items extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.items = this.props.items;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.items.length}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Items;
```

As you can see, `this.items` is retrieved from the props. On initial page load, again, this is an empty array. But after the `componentDidMount` fires in `App.js`, the constructor in `Items.js` is *not* fired, so `this.items` is never re-populated with the items.

How can I instead fire the constructor in `Items.js`? I know this is a simple example, and therefore could technically be solved by simply accessing the `props` in the `render` method, but I really need the constructor to fire, because in my actual app, I have more complex logic in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the constructor of a component is only called once, I will instead move the logic that relies on the props, to the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.props` directly in the render method of `Items` to extract the data you want.

```js
class Items extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {items.length}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I already specified that I don't wish to access `props` directly, because my actual app has extra logic in the `constructor`.